# Get type of projection from pyproj CRS object

Tags: python, proj, pyproj

I'm used to using PROJ strings/dictionaries in python where I have access to a `proj_dict['proj']` element. I have some calculations that I can only do with the PROJ.4 `geos` projection and otherwise fallback to a naive calculation. Since PROJ strings are not the preferred way of accessing this information anymore I'm wondering how I could do this same check with a pyproj `CRS` object.

Here's my example:

```
from pyproj import CRS
proj_dict = {'a': '6378137.0', 'b': '6356752.31414', 'h': '35786023.0', 'lon_0': '-89.5', 'proj': 'geos', 'sweep': 'x', 'units': 'm'} 
c = CRS.from_dict(proj_dict)
```

The only thing I see related to "geos" is the coordinate operation method:

```
<Projected CRS: +proj=geos +a=6378137.0 +b=6356752.31414 +h=357860 ...>
Name: unknown
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- undefined
Coordinate Operation:
- name: unknown
- method: Geostationary Satellite (Sweep X)
Datum: unknown
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

Is that the same thing as PROJ's `proj` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. However, it isn't exactly the same as the `proj` parameter. There are some differences. But, for your purposes of checking if it is the `geos` projection, the coordinate operation should provide what you need.

```py
>>> from pyproj import CRS
>>> geos_dict = {'a': '6378137.0', 'b': '6356752.31414', 'h': '35786023.0', 'lon_0': '-89.5', 'proj': 'geos', 'sweep': 'x', 'units': 'm'}
>> CRS(geos_dict).coordinate_operation.method_name
'Geostationary Satellite (Sweep X)'
>>> geos_dict_y = {'a': '6378137.0', 'b': '6356752.31414', 'h': '35786023.0', 'lon_0': '-89.5', 'proj': 'geos', 'sweep': 'y', 'units': 'm'}
>>> CRS(geos_dict_y).coordinate_operation.method_name
'Geostationary Satellite (Sweep Y)'
```

However, I would caution that the coordinate operation does not always exist. So, I would check for that:

```py
>>> CRS("+proj=latlon").coordinate_operation
>>> CRS("+proj=latlon")
<Geographic 2D CRS: +proj=latlon +type=crs>
Name: unknown
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- lon[east]: Longitude (degree)
- lat[north]: Latitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- undefined
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

Comment: So the property always exists (no AttributeError) but it may be `None`, right?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. The coordinate_operation will always exist.